# Attempted to load class "Mpdf" from namespace "Mpdf"

Tags: php, function, spreadsheet, mpdf, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PHPSpreadsheet to create Excel.
I want t generate the Excel file, then convert the Excel file in a PDF one.
 So I've done the following :

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception;

class DevisGenerator
{
public function runDevis()
    {
       $spreadsheet = $this->loadexcelTemplate();
       $uuid = $this->uniqidReal();
       $filename = $this->writeName($spreadsheet, $uuid);
       $this->convertPdf($spreadsheet, $filename);

    }

    public function writeName($spreadsheet, $uuid)
    {
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $worksheet->getCell('B2')->setValue('Toto');

        try {
            $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
            $filename = $uuid;
            $writer->save($filename.'.xlsx');
        }catch (Exception $e)
        {
            //TODO gestion erreur
        }
        return $filename;

    }


public function convertPdf($spreadsheet, $filename)
    {
        $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save($filename.'.pdf');



    }
```

But whan I run the code the following error appear :

> Attempted to load class "Mpdf" from namespace "Mpdf".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf"?

I did not understand this error, I have correctly insert the use statement in my code.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already got a similar issue with Mpdf.

PHPSpreadsheet supports [multiple Librairies to generate PDF](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#pdf).

I'm nut using Mpdf but Tcpdf.
I'm also not sure but you need to install them manually.

> composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf

Then in your code :

```
$writer = new Tcpdf($spreadsheet);
```

And don't forget the use statement ;)

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

After use statement before class, you should use only:

```
public function convertPdf($spreadsheet, $filename)
{
    $writer = new Mpdf($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save($filename.'.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Yeah correct, I've tried from what is inside the doc because  `$writer = new Mpdf($spreadsheet);`  it did not work from me.

Comment: Do you have phpOffice in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the fully qualified namespace when creating the instance, the use statement is not taken into account (thus the error message).

It seems like you have added a supplementary slash at the beginning of the namespace when creating your `Mpdf` instance, removing it will solve your issue.

```php
$writer = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf($spreadsheet);
```

But since you have added a `use` statement, you do not need to use the fully qualified namespace again, you can do

```php
$writer = new Mpdf($spreadsheet);
```

Comment: OW I did not see my supplementary slash.. I've tried without the slash and with the `new Mpdf($spreadsheet)`I still have the same error

Comment: If you want to use `new Mpdf($spreadsheet);` you need to keep the `use` statement at the top.  Also, I can't help but notice the `/..` in the code you posted, is that a copy paste error?

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake (I'll correct if) I have few more use under ;) I'll try Thanks for your help !

Comment: If the answer helped you, feel free to upvote it. If it solved your issue, feel free to accept it. Since you're new to stackoverflow, I suggest that you read the [What should I do when someone answers my question page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). :)